# Updating all api requests using ui-router stateParams and an interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I have a an Angular application that reuses the same templates for several locations. The urls look something like:

```
/locations/location1/
/locations/location2/
/locations/location1/about
/locations/location2/about
```

And I have a state setup that sets up a location param which my other routes set as their parent:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: '/locations/{location:[^/]*}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view/>'
  });
```

Within these page templates I have several components that make API requests. What I'd like to do is intercept all http requests to the api and prepend the location id based on the location property in $stateParams:

```
function apiInterceptor ($stateParams) {
  return {
    request: (config) => {
      config.url = $stateParams.location + '/' + config.url;
      return config;
    }
  };
}

module
.factory('apiInterceptor', apiInterceptor)
.config(function($httpProvider {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('apiInterceptor');
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me a circular dependency:

```
ng1UIRouter <- $stateParams <- apiInterceptor <- $http <- ng1UIRouter
```

I believe I could get around the circular dependency using the $injector directly, but I've read that running into this problem means you probably have some sort of architecture problem. Is there a better way to get the location id without duplicating code all over for individual api requests?

Answer (score 0):

For circular dependencies you can manually inject a service using [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

try

```
function apiInterceptor ($injector) {
  var $stateParams = $injector.get('$stateParams');
  return {
    request: (config) => {
      config.url = $stateParams.location + '/' + config.url;
      return config;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually mentioned the injector solution at the bottom of my post. I was wondering if there is a better way to architect the solution, however. Circular dependencies are apparently an indication that something has gone wrong with your thinking.